# What kind of object is exactly returning 'this' in a Jquery's .each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom, each

I have been testing for hours different codes for traveling the DOM.

```
$(element).children('.classelement').each(function(){
    alert(this) // returns "object HtmlDivElement"
    alert(this.lastChild) // returns "object Text"

    // NOTE: The last child is a <a> element
});
```

Why `this.lastChild` returns `object Text`?. If `this` returns a DOM object, why `lastChild` doesn't?

And after i have the next question: What kind of object returns a `this` inside a `.each`?

What i must to do for get an DOM object in this case?

Comment: It can be a text node if there's a space after the `<a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.lastChild) returns the last node any of type in an element (including space, tab or newline written in the file). If you need the last HTMLElement within an element, you have to use [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild).

Comment: replacing the `lastChild` with a `lastElementChild`, this returns the href of the <a>, why?

Comment: Actually `toString()` method of `a` element gives you the `href`. If you did `alert(this.lastElementChild.textContent)`, you'd get the text inside the `a`.

Comment: You are right, that was unexpected for me, but it works. Thanks:-)